# Trying to copy contents from an int Array to a Dimension Array leads to NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

In my Java programming class we got the assignment to program a game and I'm currently working on loading saved games from a file.

I read this file line by line and split it up into an array of tokens.

In this save game file the first line contains the x and y coordinates of the players figures in 8 pairs (2 players * 4 figures).

Reading and parsing the file works fine but when I try to copy the coordinates from the continuous array into the Dimension classes which store the figures positions I get a NullPointerException.

Here is the code:

```
Dimension Player0Positions[] = new Dimension[4];
Dimension Player1Positions[] = new Dimension[4];

int bufferArray[] = new int[16];

for(int i = 5; i < 21; ++i) {
  bufferArray[(i-5)] = Integer.parseInt(firstLineData[i]);
}

for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  Player0Positions[i].setSize(bufferArray[(2*i)], bufferArray[(2*i + 1)]);
  Player1Positions[i].setSize(bufferArray[(2*i + 8)], bufferArray[(2*i + 9)]);
}
```

The objects in copy to exist and I don't leave any index bounds (2*(i = 3) + 9 = 15) but I don't even get there because the code crashes at the first loop iteration throwing the exception at line `Player0Positions[i].setSize(` ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java array NullPointerException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295641/java-array-nullpointerexception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the elements of your arrays of `Dimension`s are initialized.

i.e. all `Player0Positions[i]`s and `Player1Positions[i]`s are null so when you try to invoke `.setSize` on them you get NPE.

So, you might want to initialized them first -

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
   Player0Positions[i] = new Dimension();
   Player0Positions[i].setSize(bufferArray[(2*i)], bufferArray[(2*i + 1)]);
   Player1Positions[i] = new Dimension();
   Player1Positions[i].setSize(bufferArray[(2*i + 8)], bufferArray[(2*i + 9)]);
}
```